# Manipulação de dados com datas em linha para coluna

Tags: r

tenho uma base de dados um pouco difícil de trabalhar: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A variável code são 141 diferentes. O que eu queria fazer é criar um data.frame que tivesse code como uma variável (header) e assim tivesse uma sequência de dias seguidos para cada code. Uma coluna também seria a data de dias seguidos dia. Mas tenho que levar em consideração o fato de alguns meses não terem o dia 31, por exemplo. Não faço ideia como fazer.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Só para entender: você quer passar os codes para as colunas e os dias para as linhas?

Comment: Isso, de maneira que ele fiquei sequencial de 1 em 1 dia.

Comment: Não está totalmente claro. De um exemplo de como voce quer o resultado. (pode ser como imagem do excel como vc fez) E dê uma olhada no pacote reshape2 (funções melt e dcast).

Comment: @BrunoMoreno só uma pergunta estes dados são dados da ANA?

Comment: veja essa questão [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420467/r-how-to-arrange-a-daily-time-series-of-rows-and-columns-to-a-single-column) e depois veja esse arquivo http://www.abrh.org.br/xiisrhn/anais/papers/PAP018358.pdf

Comment: Já trabalhei com dados parecidos. Talvez o **fread** do pacote:**data.table** possa te ajudar. Ele faz a leitura dos dados extremamente rápido!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, vou tentar dar uma resposta com um exemplo genérico, similar aos dados que você usou. O que você vai fazer primeiro é passar os seus dados para o formato "long", isto é, você vai transformar as colunas "day1", "day2" etc em uma única variável categórica:

Criando um data.frame de exemplo:

```
exemplo <- data.frame(code = letters,
                      day1 = rnorm(length(letters)),
                      day2 = rnorm(length(letters)), 
                      day3 = rnorm(length(letters)))

head(exemplo)
  code       day1        day2        day3
1    a -0.3851659 -0.07490578  0.38106308
2    b  4.1452620 -0.24116622 -0.40116849
3    c -0.1889001 -1.51602212  0.88170295
4    d  0.9936035 -0.44319328 -0.01682136
5    e  0.4648850 -0.58219348 -0.41819945
6    f  1.7426216  0.98757578 -0.07354605
```

Agora vamos passar este dado para o formato "long". Podemos fazer isso com a função `melt()` do pacote `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
exemplo_melt <- melt(exemplo, id.vars = "code")
head(exemplo_melt)
  code variable      value
1    a     day1 -0.3851659
2    b     day1  4.1452620
3    c     day1 -0.1889001
4    d     day1  0.9936035
5    e     day1  0.4648850
6    f     day1  1.7426216
```

Agora podemos passar novamente o data.frame para o formato "wide", utilizando a função `dacast()`. Mas faremos isso colocando os dias nas linhas e os códigos nas colunas:

```
dcast(exemplo_melt, variable~code)
  variable           a          b          c           d          e           f          g          h
1     day1 -0.38516591  4.1452620 -0.1889001  0.99360350  0.4648850  1.74262161 -1.6665135 -0.8941499
2     day2 -0.07490578 -0.2411662 -1.5160221 -0.44319328 -0.5821935  0.98757578 -2.0520208  0.4832304
3     day3  0.38106308 -0.4011685  0.8817030 -0.01682136 -0.4181995 -0.07354605  0.9177027  0.5630105
           i          j         k          l          m         n         o           p          q
1  0.2417189  0.1431401 0.1194610 -0.8504266 -0.7160816 2.3065825 0.8264834  0.42561860 -1.0942050
2 -0.9602065 -1.4234463 1.7000449 -0.3513610  0.9081842 0.9250270 1.6155795  1.10958103 -0.7349258
3 -0.7072439  3.1664578 0.1780183 -0.8852057  2.1582402 0.7957866 0.8672011 -0.09192443 -0.8870918
           r         s          t           u         v          w          x          y          z
1 -1.4388341 0.2578094  0.3369311 -0.09216785  1.742366 -0.1497611  0.1625464  1.8062656  0.7381403
2  1.2544363 1.0260923 -0.6567604 -2.47889862 -1.120961 -0.2914160 -0.6510242 -0.4099567  2.2478873
3 -0.5669763 0.1865534 -0.9974459  0.40675483  2.093616  0.4234626  0.2708611  1.8284166 -0.6641648
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Carlos Cinelli! Vou tentar utilizar este exemplo pro meu caso. Acho que vai funcionar!